# Java JScrollPane sometimes not successful resized

Tags: java, swing, synchronize

I have next part of code:

```
    final JList<String> list = new JList<String>(strings);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    /* Create scroll pane instance */
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list) {
         @Override
         public Dimension getPreferredSize()
         {
             BookFrame frame = BookFrame.instance();

             Container parent = getParent();

             return new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), parent.getHeight() - parent.getComponent(parent.getComponentCount() - 1).getHeight() - 14);
         }
    };

    /* Create button instance */
    JButton button = new JButton("Add Directory");

    /* Add new panel */
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(scroll);
    panel.add(button);
```

This code runs when program starts and sometimes button height is a normal value (ex. 15) but sometimes it's 0. I think the problem is with JScrollPane instance - it was created before JButton instance - but I can't synchronize. I tried also to add `JButton button = ...` before `JScrollPane scroll = ...` but it's not working too.

I'm newby in Java so please tell me what I do wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason you need to override the getPreferredSize() method. I would guess this is the problem.

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list)
```

I don't know what "list" is, but assuming you are using a JList then you can use:

```
list.setVisibleRowCount(...);
```

to indicate the number of rows for the size of the list. The scrollpane will then be that size and scrollbars will appear if needed.

Comment: But how can I resize my `JScrollPane` dynamically? How can I do it with `setVisibleRowCount(...)`?

Comment: @ventaquil, Any component added to the CENTER of a JFrame will resize dynamically as the frame is resized. The setVisibleRowCount() is a suggestion for when you use the pack() method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples. Download the

Comment: okay - problem is with `JPanel`. When I add scroll by `getContentPane().add(..)` method `setVisibleRowCount(..)` working good. Thanks :)